# Plot file data in gnuplot using different colors

Tags: gnuplot

Plotting data of file data.txt from line 1 to 10 in some color say red and next 10 to 20 with other similarly 20 to 30 with different color till 100th row

data.txt file is something like this:

```
1 1 
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
..
..
..
10 10

1 2
3 4
1 1
..
..
..
..

.
.
.
.

90 90
91 91
..
..
..
100 100
```

Comment: @GautamSavaliya the problem has just one line answer I plotted all points using same color but need different color for different row range

gnuplot "data.txt"

Comment: Can you please try to write in full sentences, with question marks etc.? This is insulting to the reader.

Comment: @Karl I was in a hurry. missed question mark. Is question mark important?

Comment: Punctuation is *highly* important in western languages. The order of words in a sentence changes the meaning completely, so you *need* to know where it starts and ends.

Answer (score 2):

plot 'aaa.txt' every ::1::10 w p, 'aaa.txt' every ::11::20 w p, ...

UPDATE

worked for me (well, except numbering should go from 0)

```
plot 'aaa.txt' every ::0::2 w p, 'aaa.txt' every ::3::5 w p
```

produced following graph

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can structure your data-file to separate every `data block` with 2 empty lines, you can use feature `index` with a `for loop`:

```
unset key
plot for [i=0:9] 'temp.txt' index i
```

[image: plot in 10-itemed blocks]

(my datafile is 1-10 in every block (1-10, 11-20...), structured with 2-2 empty lines)

If you can't structure your data-file (our you are just lazy ;-) ) you can use only the `for loop`:

```
plot for [i=0:9] 'temp2.txt' every ::i*10::i*10+9
```

(my datafile is 1-10 in every block (1-10, 11-20...) without empty lines)

---

**EXTENSION** (according to [Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275259/karl))

If you can structure your data-file to separate every data block with 1 empty lines, you can use feature `index` with a `for loop`

```
plot for [i=0:9] 'temp3.txt' every :::i::i
```

(my datafile is 1-10 in every block (1-10, 11-20...), structured with 1-1 empty lines)

Comment: For a single line between datasets  `... every :::i::i` (feel free to add to your anwer).

Comment: thanks, but your extension above makes no sense as it is now